# How to use AJAX for auto refresh a div or a web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

I've been trying to do this for a lot of time, but I can't. Here is my problem:
I have a web page just like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="my_div">
<span id="txt">HELLO WORLD</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want that the div "my_div" refreshes itself every X seconds, also refreshing its content. How to do this using AJAX or JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT?

Pay attention: I don't require a script that refreshes the entire page.
Pay attention(2): I've just tried to find something by Google, but I found nothing.

Please, help me. I have been having this problem for many time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @charlietfl in what sense? I need an ajax code that refreshes the div every X seconds.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using jQuery `load()` and an interval timer is about the simplest.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#my_div').load('/path/to/server/source');
}, 2000) /* time in milliseconds (ie 2 seconds)*/
```

`load()` is a shorthand method for `$.ajax`

This assumes that you would set up a server side script that only outputs the content for that element.
You could also use a selector fragment within `load` url to parse a full page for the specific content

See **[load() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Comment: YEAH! This is what I was searching for! Thanks!

Just another thing: what if I want to refresh the entire page?

Comment: If you want to reload the whole page on a timer, you can use <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">

Comment: @IanB that is **not** for using ajax to refresh content within a page

Comment: @charlietfl - it was replying to the comment from Michele about how to refresh the entire page - but admittedly it isn't using Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

you can write some stuff like

```
var doSth = function () {

  var $md = $("#my_div");
  // Do something here
};
setInterval(doSth, 1000);//1000 is miliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can dynamically update the content of an element using:

```
$("#my_div").html("... new content ...");
```

The new content replaces the original content.

Using the setInterval() method, you can cause JavaScript to be executed every period:

For example:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
   $("#my_div").html("... new content ...");
}, 1000);
```

Would replace the content every second.

Comment: You coded function($("#my_div").html("Hello")) {} instead of: function() {$("#my_div").html("Hello")}